# What is the difference and benefits of these two lines of code?

Tags: c++, list, pointers, struct

I have two lines of code I want explained a bit please. As much as you can tell me. Mainly the benefits of each and what is happening behind the scenes with memory and such.

Here are two structs as an example:

```
struct Employee 
{
    std::string firstname, lastname;
    char middleInitial;
    Date hiringDate; // another struct, not important for example
    short department;
};

struct Manager
{
    Employee emp; // manager employee record
    list<Employee*>group; // people managed
};
```

Which is better to use out of these two in the above struct and why?

```
list<Employee*>group;
list<Employee>group;
```

Comment: No. Its an example from "The C++ Programming language". Just doing some research into what would be better to use for certain situations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, `std::list` is a doubly-linked list. So both those statements are creating a linked list of employees.

```
list<Employee*> group;
```

This creates a list of *pointers to `Employee` objects*. In this case there needs to be some other code to allocate each employee before you can add it to the list. Similarly, each employee must be deleted separately, std::list will not do this for you. If the list of employees is to be shared with some other entity this would make sense. It'd probably be better to place the employee in a smart pointer class to prevent memory leaks. Something like

```
typedef std::list<std::shared_ptr<Employee>> EmployeeList;
EmployeeList group;
```

This line

```
list<Employee>group;
```

creates a list of *`Employee` objects by value*. Here you can construct Employee objects on the stack, add them to the list and not have to worry about memory allocation. This makes sense if the employee list is not shared with anything else.

Answer (score 1):

One is a list of pointers and the other is a list of objects.  If you've already allocated the objects, the first makes sense.

Comment: so the first is good if i have 20 employees I want to point to them (saves memory by not creating copies). If I havent created any employees, is it better to use the second?

Comment: Not better or worse - just different.  You need to decide where you want to create (and delete) employees.  This will help you decide if the first or second makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use the second one, if you store the "people managed" to be persisted also in another location. To elaborate: if you also have a global list of companyEmployees you probably want to have pointers, as you want to share the object representing an employee between the locations (so that, for example, if you update the name the change is "seen" from both locations).

If instead you only want to know "why a list of structs instead of a list of pointers" the answer is: better memory locality, no need to de-allocate the single Employee objects, but careful that every assignement to/from a list node (for example, through an iterator and its * operator) copies the whole struct and not just a pointer.

Answer (score 1):

The two lists are good, but they will require a completely different handling.

```
list<Employee*>group;
```

is a list of pointers to objects of type Employee and you will store there pointers to objects allocated dynamically, and you will need to be particularly clear as to who will delete those objects.

```
list<Employee>group;
```

is a list of objects of type Employee; you get the benefit (and associated cost in terms of performance) of dealing with concrete instances that you do not need to memory manage yourself.

Specifically, one of the advantages of using `std::list` compared to a plain array, is that you can have a list of *objects* and avoid the cost and risks of dealing with dynamic memory allocation and pointers.

With a list of objects, you can do, e. g.

```
Employee a;    // object allocated in the stack
list.push_back(a); // the list does a copy for you

Employee* b = new Employee....
list.push_back(*b); // the object pointed is copied
delete b;
```

With a list of pointers you are forced at using always dynamic allocation, in practice, or refer to object whose lifetime is longer than the list's (if you can guarantee it).

By using a std::list of pointers, you are more or less in the same situation as when using a plain array of pointers as far as memory management is concerned. The only advantage you get is that the list can grow dynamically without effort on your part.

I personally don't see much sense in using a list of pointers; basically, because I think that pointers should be used (always, when possible) through *smart pointers*. So, if you really need pointers, you will be better off, IMO, using a list of smart pointers provided by boost.

Answer (score 1):

The first one stores the objects by pointer. In this case you need to carefully document who owns the allocated memory and who's responsible for cleaning it up when done. The second one stores the objects by value and has full control of their lifespan.

Which one to use depends on context you haven't given in your question although I favor the second slightly as a default because it doesn't leave open the possibility of mismanaging your memory.

But after all that, *carefully* consider if `list` is actually the right container choice for you. Typically it's a low-priority container that satisfies very specific needs. I almost always favor `vector` and `deque` first for random access containers, or `set` and `map` for ordered containers.

If you do need to store pointers in the container, boost provides ptr-container classes that manage the memory for you, *or* I suggest storing some sort of smart pointer so that the memory is cleaned up automatically when the object isn't needed anymore.

Answer (score 1):

A lot depends on what you are doing.  For starters, do you really want
`Manager` to contain an `Employee`, rather than to be one: the classical
example of a manager (one of the classic OO examples) would be:

```
struct Manager : public Employee
{
    list<Employee*> group;
};
```

Otherwise, you have the problem that you cannot put managers into the
group of another manager; you're limited to one level in the management
hierarchy.

The second point is that in order to make an intelligent decision, you
have to understand the role of `Employee` in the program.  If `Employee`
is just a value: some hard data, typically immutable (except by
assignment of a complete `Employee`), then `list<Employee> group` is
definitely to be preferred: don't use pointers unless you have to.  If
`Employee` is a "entity", which models some external entity (say an
employee of the firm), you would generally make it uncopyable and
unassignable, and use `list<Employee*>` (with some sort of mechanism to
inform the `Manager` when the employee is fired, and the pointed to
object is deleted).  If managers are employees, and you don't want to
loose this fact when they are added to a group, then you have to use the
pointer version: polymorphism requires pointers or references to work
(and you can't have a container of references).

Answer (score 0):

Use the first one if you're allocating or accessing the structures separately.

Use the second one if you'll *only* be allocating/accessing them through the list.

Answer (score 0):

First one defines a list of pointers to objects, the second a list of objects.
The first version (with pointers) is preferred by most of the programmers.
The main reason is that STL is copying elements by value making sorting and internal reallocation more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use unique_ptr<> or auto_ptr<> or shared_ptr<> rather then plain old * pointers. This goes some if not the whole way of having both the expected use without much of the memory issues with using non-heap objects...